# Nuget - Installing a package which depends on a library with a higher version than my project's reference

Tags: c#, json.net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install a nuget package that depends on Newtonsoft.Json version 8.0.2. However, my project references a version 4.5.0 and I get a File Not Found exception when I run my tests. Can I get this to work without upgrading my project reference?

Comment: Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks Andrew!